# How do I host multiple domains on Ubuntu Server (Hardy Heron)?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, hosting, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out the best way to host multiple domains on my Ubuntu server. I have tried multiple options, but I can't get everything to work the way I want it to.

I want to be able to add domains without having to restart Apache each time. I tried using mod_vhost_alias (see below), but that maps www.domain.com and domain.com to different folders.

I also need to be able to use mod_rewite to map requests for domain.com/app/* to domain.com/somescript.php

current httpd.conf:
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you add all the domains that you require and then restart apache gracefully- almost all users would not notice this. It would be worth keeping separate vhost files for each domain to keep the configuration clean.

Comment: Yeah. I think this is probably the best way. I like things clean with granular control. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using mod_vhost_alias (see below), but that maps www.domain.com and domain.com to different folders.

One way around this is to symlink the second directory to the first one.